# How to add a trigger if column has updated with specific string

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to add a trigger if name has update with "NEW_" string. Below is my current trigger but its working without checking the updated value contain "NEW_" . please advice

- if user updates name from "Ann" to "NEW_Ann" trigger should work.
- if user updates name from "Ann" to "Ann111" trigger shouldn't work

Code:

```
  $this->execute("ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD COLUMN `date_` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL");

    $this->execute("CREATE TRIGGER `update_user_deleted_date` BEFORE UPDATE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

                        IF (NEW.name!= OLD.name) THEN

                        SET NEW.date_deleted = NOW();

                        END IF;

                    END ;");
```

Comment: Something sounds wrong with your application design.  Using a trigger to identify "special names" input by users seems like a poor work-around instead of solving a real problem.  What information is "NEW_" supposed to encode?  Should that be in a separate column or separate table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_user_deleted_date BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (LOCATE('NEW_', NEW.name) != 0) THEN
    SET NEW.date_deleted = NOW();
END IF;
END;
```

LOCATE('NEW_', NEW.name) != 0 means that the location of string "NEW_" is found